# What does it mean to say that determinant is multilinear?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, multilinear-algebra

Can someone clearly explain to me what is meant by the determinant being multilinear,  and what (multi-)linear functions are? I can't find a clear answer to this question.

Comment: You are confused; there is no such thing as a multilinear matrix. Matrices are just blocks of numbers; they are neither linear nor multilinear, even though matrices are usually used to _represent_ linear _maps_. You probably were reading about functions _of a matrix_ (meaning the matrix is the argument of the function) that are multilinear with respect to the columns of the matrix. Unless you can be more clear about what exactly you are asking about, there is not much to answer to here.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen You're right, I checked my notes and they're talking about the determinant that is multilinear, not a multilinear matrix. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the word ''map'' as synonym of ''function''.

A linear  function $f$  is a function of one variable $x$ such that :
$
f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y) 
$
and
$
 f(c\cdot x)=c\cdot f(x) 
$
where $c$ is an element of a field, $+$ and$\cdot$ are suitable operations  defined depending on the domain of $f$.

A $n$-linar function is a function on $n$ variables that is linear on each variable, i.e. $f(x_1,x_2, \cdots, x_i,\cdots x_n)$ is linear in $x_i$ for fixed values of $x_j\;,j\ne i$.

Some exemples:

The dot product of two vectors $\langle v,u\rangle$ is a bi-linear form since it is linear in $v$ and $u$.

The trace of a matrix tr$(A)$ is a linear function since $\lambda$tr$ (A)=$tr$(\lambda A)$

The determinant of a $n\times n$ matrix det$A$ is not a linear function, since det$(\lambda A)=\lambda^n$det$(A)$, but it is a $n$-linear function of the vectors that are columns of the matrix.

I don't understand what you means for a ''multilinear matrix" . A multilinear map can be represented by a [tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor), that in some sense is a generalization of a matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I see what linear and multilinear means. I checked my notes again and I must have misread multilinear matrix as they are only talking about the determinant that is multilinear. I'm sorry for the confusion. You're answer helped me understand what exactly linearity is. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! glad to be helpful.

Comment: The c disappeared in your definition of linearity

Comment: @Dan: tahnk you. I edit .

Comment: No problem, good answer too